# ConstraintLayout Group vs Layer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

What's the difference between `ConstraintLayout` `Group` and `Layer`?

I understand we can control the visibility of a `Group`, but can we control its `alpha` transparency as well? I want to change some of my `View`s transparency as a user drags a `SeekBar`, proportionately of the `SeekBar` value.

Comment: Only visibility is applied to members of a Group. Nothing else.

Comment: Do you know about `Layer`?

Comment: Layer doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: androidx.constraintlayout.Layer I think it will only be announced in version 2.0.0

Comment: Then we need to wait. There's zero documentation or source code I can find.

Comment: I found some blog posts about how it should work, I think it will support transparency, but it's too soon to say.

Answer (score 0):

According to the google docs

Layer can control the visibility and elevation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Layer

It can combine the view reference point aka center point of two or more view, when we want to animate those views with value animator.

Further reference here...

https://decode.agency/article/flow-and-layer-2-new-cool-views-in-constraint-layout-2-0-2/

Answer (score 0):

Layer is added in constraint layout 2.0.

It adds the ability to move and rotate/scale a group of views as if they were contained in a ViewGroup. For simple visibility manipulation use Group.